# NumberFormatException when passing String param through Jenkins choice parameter

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, automated-tests, testng

I have some automated tests for which I am using a Jenkins Parameterized project. It is a Maven project using TestNG for which I am passing values at runtime

I am using Choice Parameters to pass values as Strings.  A few of the parameters are of int type however.

I therefore convert these as follows (code simplified for illustration purposes):

```
 @BeforeClass
@Parameters({"numOfAdults"})
public void setup(String numOfAdults) {

 numOfPeople = new SearchDetails()
            .withNumberOfAdults(Integer.valueOf(numOfAdults.trim()))
```

The maven goal I pass at runtime is:

```
clean test -DsuiteFile=src\test\resources\tools\testng_custom_runner.xml -DnumAdults=$numOfAdults
```

The TestNG Suite File has the param:

```
   <parameter name="numOfAdults" value="${numAdults}"/>
```

And the Maven file as follows:

```
<properties>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
    <suiteFile>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
    <numAdults>${numAdults}</numAdults>
</properties>
//...........
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <numAdults>${numAdults}</numAdults>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

The build fails with:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$numOfAdults"
```

I'm sure there is an obvious answer (and solution) - the code runs fine in the IDE.  Is there a better / safer way to pass or convert variables via Runtime?  I have a need to expose the variables in dropdown boxes so non technical staff can run the tests with different data.

The value is passed via Jenkins Build with Parameters:
[image]

Comment: this: $numOfAdults should be translated in a number, no doubt, but isn't, and since $numOfAdults isn't a numeric value, you get that Exception

Comment: `clean test -DsuiteFile=src\test\resources\tools\testng_custom_runner.xml -DnumAdults=$numOfAdults` should probably be something like `clean test -DsuiteFile=src\test\resources\tools\testng_custom_runner.xml -DnumAdults=12345`

Comment: @Stultuske hence Integer.valueOf(numOfAdults.trim())

Comment: @assylias yes, but it needs to be parameterized, not hardcoded

Comment: @Steerpike that makes no sense at all. do you truly believe that "$numOfAdults " or "$numOfAdults" makes a difference when trying to get a numeric value out of it?

Comment: @Steerpike ehm... what Assylias did was parameterized, not hardcoded

Comment: @Steerpike Where do you define the value of the parameter?

Comment: sorry if I am not being clear, I appreciate the responses, I am primarily a tester so some of the Jenkins/Maven functionality may not be self evident.

Comment: ok, I have finished making edit - apologies, the full information had not been posted

Comment: you are using `numAdults` but the parameters is `numOfAdults`

Comment: @ajc thank you - I must have been blind from all the looking, can't believe it was something so stupid